# EF Core join on sub table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have three classes set up like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserItem> UserItems { get; set; }
}

public class UserItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework generates the tables in the SQL Server database with the correct foreign keys. I can query the `Item` and `User` to get the `UserItem` collections within like this:

```
var a = context.DBUser.Include(s => s.UserItems);
var b = context.DBItem.Include(s => s.UserItems);
```

What I am not happy about is how I get from the `User` to the `Item`. In SQL I would do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Users U
LEFT JOIN UserItems UI
    ON U.ID = UI.UserID
LEFT JOIN Items I
    ON UI.ItemID = I.ID
```

In C# I've needed to resort to this:

```
var c = from user in _context.DBUsers
    join userItem in _context.DBUserItems
        on user.ID equals userItem.UserID into ui
        from userItem in ui.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join item in _context.DBItems
        on userItem.ItemID equals item.ID into i
        from item in i.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        user,
        userItem,
        item
    };
```

Which given there should already be relationships between the tables in EF doesn't feel right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add navigations to `UserItem` also:

```
public class UserItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query can be like this:

```
var users = context.DBUser
    .Include(x => x.UserItems)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Item);
```

Also note that if you are using .NET 5, the `UserItem` "join entity" can be omitted altogether:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Which would simplify your query:

```
var users = context.DBUser.Include(x => x.Items);
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I had previously added navigations to `UserItem` but as collections not the objects and didn't consider the alternative. I have other fields in UserItem that I removed to keep the example clearer, but good to know I won't need to link like that otherwise.